# Find sublists of innermost lists in 3d list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list `l=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[9,1,2]]]`
How do I get the list `[[[1,2],[4,5]],[[7,8],[9,1]]]` using just slicing? I tried `l[:][:][:2]` but it gave me the entire 3d list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: slicing a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277100/python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested list comprehension, of course this ins't only using slicing but hopefully still useful:

```
>>> lst = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[9,1,2]]]
>>> [[subsub[:-1] for subsub in sublist] for sublist in lst]
[[[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[7, 8], [9, 1]]]
```

Comment: I would point out that it is actually not possible with only slicing.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** just noticed your outer lists do not need slicing. In that case:

Since you are on Python2 `map` works well on this one:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ft = itemgetter(slice(2))
>>> 
>>> map(map, (ft, ft), l)
[[[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[7, 8], [9, 1]]]
```

The solution below was wrongly assuming the input list was `3 x 3 x 3` and to be sliced to `2 x 2 x 2`. I'll leave it here in case anybody is looking for that case.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ft = itemgetter(slice(2))
>>> 
>>> map(map, (ft, ft), map(ft, l[:2]))
[[[1, 2], [4, 5]], [[7, 8], [9, 1]]]
```