# Python : Operator with pair of values for skip

Tags: python

I understand the basic idea behind the : operator like:

```
A[:] Returns the entire array
A[::-1] Returns the array in reverse.
```

But suppose iris.data is a n X 4 matrix, what does this do?

```
X = iris.data[:, (2,3)]
```

Comment: get all rows, columns 2 and 3

Comment: What is `iris`' type? Is it something from numpy?

Comment: `:` isn't an operator; it's just syntax for specifying a slice object. `A[:]` becomes `A[slice(None, None, None)]`; `A[::-1]` becomes `A[slice(None, None, -1)]`; `A[:, (2,3)]`is `A[(slice(None, None, None), (2,3))]` (that is, they key is a tuple consisting of a `slice` object and another tuple). In any case, it's the class's `__getitem__` method that determines what is actually *done* with the resulting key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get you the second and third column from all rows.

Here you can find some more information: [python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277100/python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array) and [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)