# Python: Array with too many Indices?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to understand the code below and what it does:

```
im = pilimage.open(img_path)
image_array = np.array(im)
imgstack = image_array[area[0]:area[1],
                       area[2]:area[3], z_stack[0]:z_stack[1]]
```

I know that it opens up an image and stores it in `im` and then converts `im` into an array and stores that in `image_array`. What I don't really understand is the last part. I don't have that much experience with python syntax so can anyone help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: A "reverse duplicate" of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277100/python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array. It's slicing the array in 3 dimensions.

Comment: What is `image_array.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an advanced-ish application of the python slice notation which you can learn about here: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).  There are a couple nuances here though:

- `area[0]:area[1]` is taking the `int` at these two indexes and making a slice `start:end` of the `image_array` following the normal rules.
- Only `numpy` arrays support the ability to slice n-dimensions at the same time. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html