# How to iterate through a section of a 2D list

Tags: python

I want to go through just a section of a 2D list, rather than the whole thing. 
Here's essentially what it is I want to do:
Let's say the user inputs the coordinates `[1,1]` (so, row 1 column 1)
If I have the 2D list:

```
[[1,3,7],
[4,2,9],
[13,5,6]]
```

Then I want to iterate through all the elements adjacent to the element at `[1,1]`

Furthermore, if the element is at a corner or the edge of the 2D list, (so basically if the user enters `[0,0],` for example) then I want to just want to get back the elements at `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, `[1,0]`, and `[1,1]`

So essentially I just want elements adjacent to a specific to a certain point in the 2D array.

Here's what I've done so far:
I've made it so that it assigns 4 variables at the start of the code: `starting_row`, `ending_row`, `starting_column`, and `ending_column`. These variables are assigned values based off of which coordinates the user wants to input (if they the row is 0 or len(list) then the for loop runs accordingly. The same goes for the columns).
Then, I use a nested for loop to go through every element

```
for row in range(row_start, row_end+1):
        for column in range(column_start, column_end+1):
            print(lst[row,column])
```

Only thing is, it doesn't seem to work correctly and often outputs the whole entire 2D list when enter a list size of more than 3x3 elements (all the lists will be square lists)

Comment: for standard list you have to use `lst[row][column]` instead of `lst[row,column]`

Comment: using `range()` and later `lst[row][column]` you can get error `index out of the range`. Better slice list - `rows = lst[(row-1):(row+2)]`. Even if you use wrong indexes you don't get error - and you don't have to check if you in `[0][0]`.

Comment: Also you can use NumPy array and have vertical slicing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277100/python-slicing-a-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the list of lists according to the given row and column. For the lower bounds, use `max` with `0` to avoid slicing with a negative index, but not so for the upper bounds since it is okay for the stopping index of a slice to be out of the range of a list:

```
def get_adjacent_items(matrix, row, col):
    output = []
    for r in matrix[max(row - 1, 0): row + 2]:
        for i in r[max(col - 1, 0): col + 2]:
            output.append(i)
    return output
```

or, with a list comprehension:

```
def get_adjacent_items(matrix, row, col):
    return [i for r in matrix[max(row - 1, 0): row + 2] for i in r[max(col - 1, 0): col + 2]]
```

so that given:

```
m = [[1, 3, 7],
     [4, 2, 9],
     [13, 5, 6]]
```

`get_adjacent_items(m, 0, 0)` returns: `[1, 3, 4, 2]`

`get_adjacent_items(m, 1, 1)` return: `[1, 3, 7, 4, 2, 9, 13, 5, 6]`

`get_adjacent_items(m, 2, 1)` returns: `[4, 2, 9, 13, 5, 6]`

`get_adjacent_items(m, 2, 2)` returns: `[2, 9, 5, 6]`

Comment: Hmm. It does work. That's interesting. I've never seen the `i for r in...` loop before. I'm guessing you're adding 2 to the rows and columns after the colons because your last element in each row/column will be 1 after the element itself (it's exclusive, so we do +2 instead of +1). Correct me if I'm wrong. Could this be written not in one line (I don't want the answer for this, maybe just a hint).

Comment: Yes you're right about why 2 is needed to be added to the stopping index of the slices (it's exclusive). I've updated my answer with the equivalent implementation with nested `for` loops.